# how to put each inside append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, each

Here is my code

```
$('#payment_detail').append(
                        '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">'+
                        '<thead>'+
                        '<th>Payment Date</th>'+
                        '<th>Payment Value</th>'+
                        '<th>Verified By</th>'+
                        '</thead>'+
                        '<tbody>'+
                            $.each(response.payments, function (key, value) {
                                return '<td>'+ value.payment_date +'</td> <td>'+ value.payment_value +'</td> <td>'+ value.created_by +'</td>'
                            })+
                        '</tbody>'+
                        '</table>'
                    );
```

but the view looks like this
[image]

can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Build the string outside and than append that....

Comment: @epascarello didnt work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
('#payment_detail').append(
                        '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">'+
                        '<thead>'+
                        '<th>Payment Date</th>'+
                        '<th>Payment Value</th>'+
                        '<th>Verified By</th>'+
                        '</thead>'+
                        '<tbody id="dtDetails"></tbody></table>');

    $.each(response.payments, function (key, value) {
        $("#dtDetails").append('<tr><td>' + value.payment_date + '</td> <td>' + value.payment_value + '</td> <td>' + value.created_by + '</td></tr>');
    });
```